# WPF TreeView with multiple item sources

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I am stuck on a problem with the wpf treeview control in my current application. I'm building a visual studio like application (editor with project tree) for my school.

Now i have the problem that I can't display this structure in my treeview.

I'd like to have the following structure:

```
+ Project
  - Folder
    -- Folder
    -- File
  - Folder
  - File

+ Project
...
```

I've tried a lot of things I found around the internet, but not one of them really did work..

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're going to have to give us more information than that. What's your data look like (the structure of your classes, etc)? What have you tried? Why didn't it work? Help us help you.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried HierarchicalDataTemplate ?
You can find solution here : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeViewWithViewModel.aspx

Comment: @user769688: You misunderstand `HierarchicalDataTemplate`. The `TreeView`'s items-source should be a collection of `Project`s. Each of the `Project` objects should have a collection of `Folder` and `File` objects (as should each `Folder` object). The objects should be nested in a tree already, the `TreeView` and `HierarchicalDataTemplate` just visualize it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you always mention that you need multiple ItemsSources i think your problem is that your project object has two collections: Files & Folders and you don't know how to put both of them into the HierarchicalDataTemplate's ItemsSource.

The solution to that is the [`CompositeCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection.aspx). Note that if you construct it in XAML you will not have a DataContext inside the `CollectionContainers`, so you cannot bind the `Collection` property that easily.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use a `DataTemplateSelector`, see the example here:

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector